# AppTrap alternative? (Deleting Applications)

Tags: macos, mac, product-rec, trash

I've been using [AppTrap](http://konstochvanligasaker.se/apptrap/) for some time now, however it's no longer being maintained.  Is their something similar out there that's being actively maintained and will work with the next OS release?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/) out.
I think it has a great UI and you can use it like App Zapper (Drag app onto window).

You can also set it to totally clear the app out when you drag it to the trash by activating SmartDelete in the preferences window:

[image: AppCleaner Preferences]

Comment: I like this, but I really want something that will give me the option to delete all the files associated with the application by just simply dragging the application to the trash, like AppTrap.

Comment: Updated answer to provide information about SmartDelete.

Comment: what an idiot I am, thanks for this, it's just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Hazel also provides this feature. Turn it on by checking "App Sweep" in Hazel's Trash preferences:

http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php

Afterwards, it will offer to throw away an application's support files when you move it to the Trash.